# In Cypher, how can I create a relationship if it doesn't exist; update property if it does

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cypher

In Cypher in Neo4J, given two nodes, if there's no relationship between them, I'd like to create a relationship (of type Foo) with a weight property of one.  If this relationship already exists, I'd like to increment its weight property.

Is there a good way to do this in a single Cypher query?  Thanks!

Edit: Some additional details:
The nodes are already created, unique, and in an index.

Comment: Are you okay with using a SNAPSHOT version of neo4j? In neo4j 1.8 you can update the graph using Cypher, but not in any other versions.

Comment: So essentially you are looking to scan all nodes and if connected, increment, if not, create relationship?

Comment: Nicholas, thanks for response. I added some additional details; the nodes are unique and indexed, so I don't think I should have to scan all the nodes.  But, other than that, your comment is correct: if connected, increment, if not, create relationship.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is exactly why we added `CREATE UNIQUE` in 1.8.

```
START a=node(...), b=node(...)
CREATE UNIQUE a-[r:CONNECTED_TO]-b
SET r.weight = coalesce(r.weight?, 0) + 1
```

Read more about `CREATE UNIQUE` [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-create-unique.html), the question mark [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-where.html#where-default-true-if-property-is-missing), and coalesce [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-function.html#functions-coalesce).

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.  I knew about RELATE, but not the coalesce phrase.  What exactly does the "?" do?

Comment: Since Neo4j 2.0 the ? operator has been removed. See: http://neo4j.com/docs/snapshot/query-operators.html#query-operators-comparison

Comment: Create unique is now deprecated, use MERGE instead: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/

Answer (score 11):

To complete Andres answer, question mark at the end of a property is now an error with Neo4j 2.
So request will be :

```
MATCH a, b
WHERE a(...) AND b(...)
CREATE UNIQUE a-[r:CONNECTED_TO]->b
SET r.weight = coalesce(r.weight, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, CREATE UNIQUE has since been deprecated (see [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/create-unique/)). It looks like you can do something similar with MATCH and MERGE:

```
                MATCH (a:Person {name: 'Wonder Woman'})
                MERGE (b:Person {name: 'Aries'})
                MERGE (a)-[r:FOUGHT]->(b)
                ON CREATE SET r.weight = 1
                ON MATCH SET r.weight = r.weight + 1
```

So here, Wonder Woman fought Aries at least once, else it will increment the weight.