# how to create unique relationships neo4j 2.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create some unique relationships between entities in neo4j. Right now I have authors and articles, with a Authored relationship between them. I want to create a CoAuthored relationship between the entities

Like so

```
match (a)-[r]->(b)<-[r2]-(c)
create (a)-[new:CoAuthor]->(c)
```

However, I would like to create a unique co-author relationship, but update the weight if it already exists. I saw this postm but the syntax is no longer supported [In Cypher, how can I create a relationship if it doesn't exist; update property if it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354401/in-cypher-how-can-i-create-a-relationship-if-it-doesnt-exist-update-property)

```
SyntaxException: This syntax is no longer supported (missing properties are now returned as null). Please use (not(has(<ident>.weight)) OR <ident>.weight=<value>) if you really need the old behavior.
```

I do not quite understand what it is that I am replacing. I looked at the Merge command, but can't quite get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to replace `create` with `merge` in this particular case.

```
match (a)-[r]->(b)<-[r2]-(c)
merge (a)-[new:CoAuthor]->(c)
on create set new.weight=1
on match set new.weight=new.weight+1
```

Comment: Merge does not seem to guarantee uniqueness. I ran a lot of these queries really fast and it still created duplicated relationships. Am I missing something trivial here?